# How to pull all data from where statement including duplicated records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Recently I got a task to pull the data from excel spreadsheet and provide all telephone numbers for every shop. This sound 5 minutes job so I did last time without any issue. I found however, a catch in this task because of lot of duplication of ids.

There is over 9000 of records and the condition is to retrieve all the  records **with same order** from excel speadsheed I have received.

For example, I have following list of shops in Excel

```
ID, 
121 
123 
124 
121
124
```

but I am getting only unique records

> ID, 
>       121 
>       123 
>       124

At the moment I did few attempts with no success and reckon using cursor would be solution I am looking for but due to time I do not have I am would like to ask you for favour and help me solve this task.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: There isn't a select distinct somewhere by any chance?

Comment: Hi Harry, no that is the case, we are using Sql 2016. I had similar issue before but there were lot less records so I did in batches but now it  is way too much to do this that way.

Comment: Is there any other option to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `values()` and `join` instead of `in`:

```
select t.*
from (values (121, 1), (123, 2), (124, 3), (121, 4), (124, 5), . . .
     ) v(id, ord) left join
     t
     on t.id = v.id
order by v.ord;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, that is too complicated. I have over 9000 records so  it would take ages to select them. Thanks anyway

Comment: @piotr . . . Store the records in a temporary table.